# Facebook app review failed: login dialog display type

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The submission has been failed with following feedback from Facebook:

> For the login dialog, please use the JavaScript SDK without specifying
>   an explicit display type. If you have special requirements precluding
>   use of the SDK, set height and width on your window.open() call to
>   properly size the dialog. People must have the complete option to
>   change their audience settings.

But, I show login dialog using `FB.login` method without specifying any display type. This is how login dialog look like

[image: Login dialog]

[image: Permissions dialog]

This is how I invoke login dialog

```
FB.login(function (response) {
  ...
}, {
  scope: 'publish_actions,publish_stream,user_photos'
});
```

I have two questions:

1. Why didn't I pass the review?
2. May specifying SDK version 'v2.0' help?

Regarding my 2nd question, permissions dialog in SDK v2.0 looks little bit different:

[image: Permissions dialog v2.0]

Might this be the reason that submission was declined?

P.S. I can't just try v2.0 because there is only one attempt left

> Your last 2 app submissions received the same feedback from our review
>   team. Please address this feedback before you submit again, otherwise
>   you'll be blocked temporarily from submitting your app for review

Comment: _“because there is only one attempt left”_ – it says you might get blocked _temporarily_, not “forever”. (I think they make you take a timeout of three or four days, if you don’t address the issues they mentioned in their feedback.) I’d just switch to v2.0 (new SDK version, different URL), describe that you’re using `FB.login` without specifying a display type – and ask them to check that again nd be more specific if they still think you’re doing it wrong.

Comment: Hey. We are also facing the same issue. Could you post more details about how you got it approved from Facebook. Thanks.